# Segmentation fault in PyString_AsString function

Tags: c++, python

C++ Code

```
//quicktest.cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <new>
extern "C" 
{
    int test1(PyObject *src)
    {
    char *src1 = PyString_AsString(src);  // <-- segmentation fault
    return 0;
    } 
}
```

Python code

```
import ctypes
test_lib = ctypes.CDLL('./quicktest.so');
test_lib.test1("test")  #  <-- segmentation fault
```

There is a segmentation fault ("received SIGSERV") in PyString_AsString call.

Linux 64 bit, python2.7

Can you explain, where is the error in my code?

Comment: Use a debugger (so compile your C++ stub with `g++ -Wall -g`, then use `gdb python`). I guess that `src` might be null or uninitialized.

Comment: Are you sure that ctypes will pass the string as a `PyObject *`? It's possible that `ctypes` converts the object to a `char *`, hence the segfault. In fact reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions-continued) it states "all Python types except integers, strings, and bytes objects have to be wrapped in their corresponding ctypes type, so that they can be converted to the required C data type" which means that the string `"text"` is automatically converted to `char *` and passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks Basile, but I've already used gdb. Howewer, it's right.

Comment: Thanks, Bakuriu, you were right - changing "PyObject *" to "char *" helped.

Comment: Of course I don't need PyString_AsString anymore.

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT: the code in the question has changed]

<s>The function PyString_AsString needs a pointer to PyObject and you are passing a pointer to char.
[Python/C API Reference Manual](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html)</s>

From ctypes documentation ([Calling functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions)):

> byte strings and unicode strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that contains their data (char * or wchar_t *)

Now, after changing the question, you are improperly casting a pointer to char to pointer to PyObject when calling the test1 function.

So the function test1 is receiving a pointer to char and, at the end of the day, PyString_AsString is receiving a pointer to char converted to pointer to PyObject wrongly.

To learn more:
[Python C/API tutorial](http://koichitamura.blogspot.com.br/2008/06/this-is-small-python-capi-tutorial.html)

Comment: As I see in my post, I pass PyObject * to the function, not char *. So you are wrong.

Comment: Sorry beatt, you're right, but I've answered just after your comment " changing "PyObject *" to "char *" helped.". I will try fix my answer.